# What's the difference between operation and block in NSOperation?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

When I use following codes:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
let operation = BlockOperation()
for i in 0..<10 {
    operation.addExecutionBlock({
        print("===\(Thread.current)===\(i)"
})
}
queue.addOperation(operation)
```

I create a asynchronous queue to execute these operations.
And if I use codes like following:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
for i in 0..<10 {
    queue.addOperation(
        print("===\(Thread.current)===\(i)"
)
}
```

When I make the queue concurrent，they produce the same result.
But when I set

```
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
```

to make the queue serial, they are different!

The first one still print the unordered result like the concurrent queue. But the second one can print the ordered result.

So what's the difference between them? When I want to use NSOperation, which one should I use? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The `addOperation()` call in your question is not valid code. You need to create an `Operation` object and add that to your queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs on OperationQueue tell you about concurrency and order of execution of the blocks you submit. You should read the Xcode article on OperationQueue. Here is a relevant bit:

> An operation queue executes its queued operation objects based on
>   their priority and readiness. If all of the queued operation objects
>   have the same priority and are ready to execute when they are put in
>   the queue—that is, their isReady method returns true—they are executed
>   in the order in which they were submitted to the queue. However, you
>   should never rely on queue semantics to ensure a specific execution
>   order of operation objects. Changes in the readiness of an operation
>   can change the resulting execution order. If you need operations to
>   execute in a specific order, use operation-level dependencies as
>   defined by the Operation class.

Comment: When I set queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 to make the queue serial, it has only one thread. So the result must be ordered.

Comment: Yes, the results will be ordered, but the dependencies of the operations in the queue determine the order in which they are executed.

Comment: If I use the synchronous queue, is the order still determined by the dependencies of operations?

Comment: I don't think OperationQueues have a synchronous variant. Instead, you create an OperationQueue and set it's maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1. GCD has dispatch queues, which you create with dispatch_queue_create. You can create serial or concurrent dispatch queues. That's probably what you're thinking of.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used GCD before, nowadays I try using Operation and have some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check please the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsblockoperation/1414623-addexecutionblock) regarded `addExecutionBlock:` function. It just adds the specified block to the receiver's list of blocks to perform *in context* of executing operation.

If you would like to do it synchronously, here is a code sample:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
for i in 0..<10 {
    let operation = BlockOperation {
        print("===\(Thread.current)===\(i)")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

> When I want to use NSOperation, which one should I use?

Use the second one.

Comment: I'm sorry I used the wrong words. It should be serial and concurrent.

Comment: @Qyy https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html
According to the doc there are three distinct types of queue: serial, concurrent and main dispatch queue. Maybe do you mean a `concurrent` queue in terms of Apple doc?

Comment: Yes. I make the queue serial or concurrent by change the maxConcurrentOperationCount.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.

In this case:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
let operation = BlockOperation()
for i in 0..<10 {
    operation.addExecutionBlock({
        print("===\(Thread.current)===\(i)"
})
}
queue.addOperation(operation)
```

Inside the BlockOperation, blocks are asynchronous while the BlockOperation itself 
is synchronous. So it actually is a synchronous queue.

So the use of `queue.addOperation(operation)` is nonsense. Instead of it,
I should use `operation.start()` because this is a synchronous queue.

The function addExecutionBlock() should be used when you need a synchronous queue.

The function addOperation() should be used when you need a asynchronous queue.

Answer (score 0):

Difference -> BlockOperation has a `addDependency` whereas OperationQueue() needs to `addOperations`. Following code with console output will elaborate:

```
let opQueue = OperationQueue()
opQueue.addOperation {
   print("operation 1")
}

let operation2 = BlockOperation {
   print("operation 2")

}
let operation3 = BlockOperation {
   print("operation 3")
}
operation2.addDependency(operation3)

opQueue.addOperation(operation2)
opQueue.addOperation(operation3)
```

Console output:

```
operation 1
operation 3
operation 2
```